# Compiling error while compiling two java files in the same package that use each other

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation, package, javac

Suppose we have two .java files in the same directory.

Test.java:

```
public class Test {
    public void func() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.func();
    }
}
```

If I write in the command line: **javac Main.java**
it creates the Main.class and automatically creates Test.class and for running this program I use : **java Main**

but when I add **package myPack** statement in the first line of two files everything changes.
and the structure of the files is as follows:

myPack
├── Main.java
└── Test.java

If I write **javac Main.java** the compiler says:

> Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
> Test t = new Test();

and I should compile both of them at the same time. **(javac Main.java Test.java)**

Question 1) Why it happens?

Question 2) When I compiled both files I cant run program with **java Main.**

> (Error: Could not find or load main class Main ).

What's the problem?

Question 3) I read somewhere you should compile and run this from the parent directory like this :
**javac myPack/Main.java** (it automatically creates Test.class file)
and then **java myPack.Main** . this way the program works properly.
but why should we compile and run programs from the parent directory with this syntax?

Comment: Try `cd ..` and then `javac myPack/Main.java`. NB it is customary to use only lowercase in package names. Don't ask me why.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for compiling

```sh
# compile all files .java in folder ./myPack and outputing in ./folder-compiled
javac -d folder-compiled $(find ./myPack -name '*.java')
```

So you can run all compiled class with this

```sh
# run all Main.class already compiled in ./folder-compiled
java -cp folder-compiled Main
```

> this example above will work because I'm considering your classpath is in myPack/* and you are not working with modular classpath jdk9+ in other way may be diferent

*the other simple and easy way is working with building tools such as gradle or maven*